# How is it better to wait an asynchronous method to be finished in iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, gdata-api

everybody.
I want to understand, how i shoud procceed situations when an asynchronous method has "didFinish:@selector(SEL)" parameter.
My code example is:

```
//
// Authentication check
- ( void )authenticationSuccess: ( GDataServiceTicket* ) ticket
         authenticatedWithError: ( NSError* ) error {

    if ( error == nil )
    {
        NSLog( @"authentication success" );
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog( @"authentication error" );
    }
}
//

- ( void ) fetchFeedOfSpreadsheets {

    //create and authenticate to a google spreadsheet service 
    if ( !(mService) )
    {
        GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *service = [self spreadsheetService];
        [mService autorelease];
        mService = [service retain];    
    }

    // check autentication success ( invoke "authenticationSuccess" method for debug success & error )
    [mService authenticateWithDelegate: self
               didAuthenticateSelector:@selector(authenticationSuccess:
                                                 authenticatedWithError:) ];


    // HERE I WANT TO MAKE A PAUSE AND WHAIT THE RESULT, EITHER I AUTHENTICATED OR NOT
    // AND MAKE AN "IF" STATEMENT TO CONTINTUE WORKING ON SERVER, OR RETURN ERROR


    //fetch retrieves the feed of spreadsheets entries 
    NSURL *feedURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: kGDataGoogleSpreadsheetsPrivateFullFeed ];
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [mService fetchFeedWithURL: feedURL
                               delegate: self
                      didFinishSelector: @selector(spreadsheetsTicket:finishedWithFeed:
                                                   error: ) ];

    // HERE I WANT TO WAIT SECOND TIME. I WANT "spreadsheetsTicket:        
    // finishedWithFeed:error:" TO PROCCEED ERROR AND PUT A FEED IN SOME NSARRAY OBJECT
    // AND AFTER THAT I WANT TO WORK WITH THAT NSARRAY RIGHT HERE
}
```

I's clear, that i can push the code i want into the end of "authenticationSuccess" method section, but it's also clear, that it's a wrong a way to solve the proble. There a number of situations like this, where i call an asynchronous method with a selector parameter, and i want to find a solution providing me a flexible code writing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard practice in Objective-C to put the code to be executed after the authentication in the `authenticationSucess:` method. You might not like it, but that is life.

Many people had the same complaint as you, so 
on iOS 4 and later, there's something called blocks which allow you to write the code to be executed after the authentication in the method which initiates the authentication, as in

```
[mService authenticateAndExecute:^{ 
                 code to be executed when successfully authenticated ;
          }            whenError:^{
                 code to be executed when authentication failed;
          } ];
```

But in this case you need to modify the API, which is possible by using categories. See [this blog post](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html) by Mike Ash. He has many other posts on blocks on the same blog, which are also very instructive.

Comment: But modifing gdata-objectivec-client with blocs is a harder way then make this bubled logic :/ ..so.. i guess i have no choose, and make insertions of code into "didFinish:@selector" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a library that works asynchronously (and therefore doesn't block your UI), you should have a good reason for trying to force it to work synchronously.

You should be checking for an authentication error at the end of your `authenticationSuccess:authenticatedWithError:` method, and calling the next request from there if there's a success. Similarly, in your `spreadsheetsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:` check for an error, and continuing processing if there isn't one. It might be a better design to do that continued work in a separate method, but that's up to you.

Is there a specific reason you want to use the GData API in a synchronous fashion?